# Foreach em campos

Tags: php, html, foreach

Boa tarde. Estou com problema ao mostrar os dados de um formulario, onde podem ter vários endereços e dentro desses endereços podem ter vários envolvidos. Tentei algo como:

```
foreach($input[endereco] as $key => $endereco){
    foreach($input[envolvidos] as $envolvidos){
       echo $endereco.' - '$envolvidos[$key].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Mas assim, se tiver 2 endereços, vai mostrar apenas 2 envolvidos e não vai importar se é do primeiro cadastro ou do segundo .

Abaixo está uma imagem do formulário.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: seu código tá correto? não deveria fechar os `foreach`??

Comment: não está com erro de sintaxe amigo

Comment: agora não mais :P

Comment: `$input[endereco]` dará erro de sintaxe, supondo que `endereco` não seja uma constante da aplicação.

Comment: eu utilizo laravel e $input[campo] é algo que posso utilizar

Comment: Como é que teria que ser? Não consegui entender direito.

Comment: Você poderia dar um `print_r($input)` para ver como está esse array?

Comment: Acabei optando por utilizar de outra forma o cadastro, pq da maneira que eu tava fazendo, não ia dar certo. Ao debugar a variavel $input, mostrava vários arrays

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem a ideia, a lógica no `foreach` está um pouco confusa.

Admitindo que na variável `$input` você possui vários *endereços*, e dentro dos endereços, vários *envolvidos*, acredito que ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
foreach($input[enderecos] as $endereco){
    foreach($endereco[envolvidos] as $envolvido){
       echo $endereco.' - '$envolvido.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Dessa forma seriam exibidos todos os endereços e seus respectivos envolvidos (quebrando em cada linha esse *par*).

Comment: Tentei utilizar assim tbm, mas quando eu coloco que no endereço São Paulo tem o envolvido Luiz e Linhares, no endereço Rio de Janeiro tem o envolvido Pedro e Anderson, ao utilizar o foreach ele vai retornar que no endereço São Paulo tem os envolvidos Luiz, Linhares, Pedro e Anderson e no Endereço São Paulo tbm estaria mostrando os 4